# Install libfreenect (Kinect 360) on a Raspberry Pi Make error

Tags: pi-2, make

I am trying to install libfreenect on a Raspberry Pi using the instructions found here: http://blog.bitcollectors.com/adam/2016/01/kinect-support-for-raspberry-pi-using-libfreenect/

On step 4, line 8 when I run *make* I get the following error:
*make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.*

There is no make file in this directory, but the make step worked fine in step 3.  Any ideas why I am getting this error?  I am generally a Linux noob and appropriate instructions are appreciated.

Comment: I have re-tried the methods with the most recent version of libfreenect and after an OS upgrade...same results.